# how to make ebs volume usable by docker stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-swarm

I'm building a multi-tier env in AWS using ansible and Docker (running in Swarm). I have one master and 2 worker nodes. I'm using Docker stack to create services in the swarm using the following command:

```
docker stack deploy -c myStack.yml myTest
```

I have 2 questions:

1. my first question is all my nodes keeps running out of space because Docker is using only ec2's root volume. How can I instruct Docker to create services in EBS volume instead?
2. is it possible to only create services in workers nodes only and not create any services in manager? can I use the swarm manager for managing the nodes only?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with your second questions, since it is easier.

You can add label to your nodes, and then use constraint when you create your service (stack is the same). e.g

```
docker node update --label-add "role=worker" .... # on all your worker nodes
docker service create --constraint "node.labels.role==worker" ...
```

---

For your first question, you need data persistent. There are some solutions.

[Flocker](https://clusterhq.com/flocker/introduction/) is a large solution. It has more support, more options and more secure. It is also much difficult to configure.

[Blocker](https://github.com/joeduffy/blocker) is the one I current using. It have to be install on every node, and I can confirm it is working and working very well. Syntax is like,

```
docker service create --mount type=volume,target=/data,source=vol-08a1211f22864700c,volume-driver=blocker ....
```

I hope this is enough info for you to start your research.

Comment: I have a question, currently I'm using an ebs (which is root volume of ec2) for docker swarm but whenever I shut down the manager and the two worker nodes after I start them again I see the services but they wont be reachable by ssh and they lose their configuration. Is this why you said that I need persistence? and need to use Flocker or Blocker?

Comment: I saw your question. It is not relative to data persistence. Swarm manager is not design for this. You may encounter a bug. Maybe create a minimum test case and submit it to GitHub issue?